# mySQL tree relationships with complex entities

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hierarchical-data

I'm busy putting together a database with a structure as follows:

Table named articles has a 1-to-many relationship with the table named field_groups. field_groups has a 1-to-many relationship with the table named fields, however, field_groups requires a tree structure where each field_group can be a parent or child to another field group.

I'm aware of the nested set model for dealing with hierarchical relationships but I'm not sure that this will work well in this case. Not only would I need to maintain the hierarchy of nodes but also retrieve related data for each node, I can't see away around this without looping through and querying for each separate node(a theoretically infinite number of nodes).

For this reason I'm considering going with mongoDB or similar because I believe it will handle this situation quite elegantly, it's worth mentioning that field_groups will only ever be queried in the context of its parent article. I'm aware of some of the various criticism of mongoDB, so I'm not here to ask for advice on that, what I really want to know before committing to another DB solution is - is there a known way to deal with this sort of situation in mySQL?

Comment: So, you have a hierarchy of field_groups, and you have a table of articles. So, what's the problem?

Comment: Please see my comment below.

Comment: sorry, I'm probably being a bit dense. You're using a nested set, not an 'adjacency list' so the comment below would appear to be irrelevant. I think the model you've adopted is entirely sensible - but I haven't understood why you think there's a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm worried that I'm being totally dense to be honest. So, admittedly by implementing a nested set instead of an adjacency list I've resolved the problem of multiple self joins, but that still leaves looping through each field_group to get the related fields. For example, I have 5 top level field_groups, each have 5 child field_groups, and each child has 5 child field_groups of their own - recursively looping through each field_group to get the related fields entries that would be 125 queries. I hope this makes sense, and that I haven't missed some glaringly obvious solution.

Comment: Consider posting up a sqlfiddle - that shows where you've got to so far, and why you think (and you might be right) that the final part of the puzzle cannot be resolved with one single join.

Comment: While putting together an sqlfiddle I realised that I was being an dense and it's prefectly possible with a single join, but after continuing I ran into the same issue described here: http://blog.lphuberdeau.com/wordpress/2006/06/nested-sets-large-amount-of-data-need-more-ram/

Comment: Unfortunately thousands of nodes is a very likely scenario for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need a field_group_id in fields which would be a foreign key to the field_groups table and you need an article_id in the field_groups table which would be a foreign key to the articles table. Also, you need a parent_id in the field_groups table which would be a foreign key to the field_groups table. If you have this structure in the database table you can get your data using queries with joins. You can make things easier by using an ORM above your MySQL. Of course, you can switch to MongoDB, I just wanted to show you that there is a solution to your problem in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already tried implementing a structure as you suggest - my main worry is that I will need one self-join for every level in the hierarchy, which could kill performance for deeper nested field_groups. On top of that because each field_group can have many related fields entries as far as I can see it would still be necessary to loop through each field_group and query for its fields. All of this could lead to a potentially huge number of queries to retrieve a single article and its associated data. This is what's lead me to consider a document based DB.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid problem. I believe you can reduce the magnitude of the problem if you define indexes where needed, you can also use cache systems, such as Redis. Also, the problem's magnitude highly depends on the number of records in your tables. Finally, you might consider creating tables for the relations containing only the key pairs to speed up foreign key link usages.